# Can install sass-loader in Vue 3 project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, sass, vue-cli

I am trying to add sass/scss loader AFTER creating a project with vue CLI.
I ran this script:
`$ npm install -D sass-loader@^10 sass`
and I am receiving following error:

```
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

It worked for me in empty project that i created to test this. But in my project does not work.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04
this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "hikegear",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "sortablejs": "^1.13.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.0.1",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try deleting your `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder and then installing your dependencies again

```
rm -r node_modules package.json
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. add following dependecis in your package.json and run npm i.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "sass-loader": "^7.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.22.10",
  }
```

for add global variables you need to make vue.config.js in root directory if not exist. then add your scss varibale file.

```
module.exports = {
 
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: '@import "@/assets/styles/file.scss";',
        implementation: require('node-sass')
      },
    },
  },

};
```